# Liferay action not working

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, liferay

I'm new to Liferay, and I'm a little confused on how it works. I'm having a really tough time understanding its structure (I don't usually do!).

I'm just trying to make a simple portlet to scale out from that point and be able to program portlets, even if in a simple and archaic way (I don't really care; I just need this working in a few days). An important point to achieve this, is to be able to use actions.

Check this code. I downloaded this example from a website, but it's not working for me (I use Liferay 6.2):

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>

User Name is : <b> ${userName}</b>

<portlet:defineObjects />

<portlet:actionURL name="addName" var="addNameUrl"></portlet:actionURL>
<br>
<form action="${addNameUrl}" method="post">
<input type="text" name="userName"><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

This is my controller portlet:

```
public class CustomMVCPortlet extends MVCPortlet {

    @ProcessAction(name="addName")
    public void addName(ActionRequest actionRequest,
            ActionResponse actionResponse) throws IOException,     PortletException, PortalException, SystemException{

        String userName = ParamUtil.get(actionRequest, "userName", StringPool.BLANK);
        actionRequest.setAttribute("userName", userName);
    }
```

This is supposed to work this way: you write a string in the input field, click on the submit button, and what you wrote should appear in the view as "User name is: whatYouWrote". But I don't see anything more than this:

Somehow, actions are not working properly here. What change should I perform to get this working? Can anyone tell me in a simple way how these actions work?

Comment: Hello. Could you edit the question and add the picture of the result?. Is there any stacktrace on your log or do you even try to debug if the action is been processed?

Comment: What do you mean by stating "not working properly"? Is the action not called at all?
Btw. Did you add the reference to the CustomMVCPortlet class to the portlet.xml as well?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code before try this i hope you did with all the configuration regarding database and all -

This is your Jsp page:

```
<%
  PortletURL addNameURL = renderResponse.createActionURL();
  addNameURL.setParameter(
        ActionRequest.ACTION_NAME, "addName");
%>
<form name="fm" action="<%= addNameURL.toString() %>" method="POST">

    <input name="userName" label="User Name"/>

    <button type="submit" value="save"/>
</form>
```

This is my controller portlet:

```
public class CustomMVCPortlet extends MVCPortlet {

public void addName(ActionRequest actionRequest,
        ActionResponse actionResponse) throws IOException, PortletException        {

    String userName= ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "userName");
// 1. Instantiate an empty object of type (entityName)Impl
   entityName xyz = new entityName)Impl;
// 2. Generate a unique primary key to be set 
  long employeeId = 0l;
  try { 
    employeeId = CounterLocalServiceUtil.increment();
  } catch (SystemException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
// 3. Set the fields for this object
  xyz .setEmployeeId (employeeId );
  xyz .setUserName(userName);
// 4. Call the Service Layer API to persist the object
 try {
   xyz = (entityName)LocalServiceUtil.add(entityName)(xyz);
 }
catch (SystemException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```